# I'm trying to scroll to a particular portion of my TableLayout using scrollTo()

Tags: android, android-tablelayout, scrollto

I have a TableLayout within ScrollView:

```
ScrollView helpSV;
TableLayout myTL;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_help);

    helpSV = (ScrollView) findViewById(R.id.helpScrollView);
    myTL = (TableLayout) findViewById(R.id.myTableLayout);
}
```

Also, on clicking a button, a function is made to run:

```
            <Button
            android:id="@+id/regButton"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:background="@drawable/button"
            android:gravity="left|center_vertical"
            android:onClick="register"
            android:paddingLeft="20dp"
            android:text="Registration"
            android:textColor="#fff" />
```

register() function is as follows:

```
public void register(View view) {
    int index = 5;
```

> final View child = myTL.getChildAt(index);

```
    new Handler().post(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            helpSV.smoothScrollTo(0, child.getBottom());
        }
    });
}
```

For some reason, my app force closes on clicking the button. I've been at this for hours, referred to similar questions but nothing helped so far..

Help? Thanks in advance...

Error log:

```
 Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
        at com.android.aashima.my_app.HelpActivity.register(HelpActivity.java:65)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:507)
            at android.view.View$1.onClick(View.java:2139)
            at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:2485)
            at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:9080)
            at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:587)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:130)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:3687)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:507)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:867)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:625)
            at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

XML:

```
<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:background="@drawable/redblack"
android:padding="5dp"
android:id="@+id/helpScrollView">

<TableLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:id="@+id/myTableLayout">

    <TableRow
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/row1">

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/regButton"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:background="@drawable/button"
            android:gravity="left|center_vertical"
            android:onClick="register"
            android:paddingLeft="20dp"
            android:text="REGISTRATION"
            android:textColor="#fff" />
    </TableRow>
<TableRow
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
        android:id="@+id/row6">

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/regImg"
            android:src="@drawable/scr5"/>
    </TableRow>

    <TableRow
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:layout_marginTop="50dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="50dp"
        android:id="@+id/row7">

        <Button android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="right"
            android:text="@string/back"
            android:id="@+id/back1"
            android:background="@drawable/roundedbutton"
            android:padding="10dp"/>
    </TableRow>

    <TableRow
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        android:id="@+id/row8">

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/locImg"
            android:src="@drawable/scr72"/>
    </TableRow>

    <TableRow
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        android:id="@+id/row9">

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/locImg2"
            android:src="@drawable/scr9"/>
    </TableRow>

    <TableRow
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        android:id="@+id/row10">

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/locImg3"
            android:src="@drawable/scr10"/>
    </TableRow>

    <TableRow
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        android:id="@+id/row11">

        <Button android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="right"
            android:text="@string/back"/>
    </TableRow>

</TableLayout>
```

Comment: Can we see the log error? And the layout XML?

Comment: yep..I've edited my post

Comment: Can you highlight the line, where you get exception?

Comment: @spgodara.. did.. please take a look

Comment: This means, most probably `myTL` is `null`. If it is so, check if you are setting correct layout file. Sometimes due to similar layout names, this may happen.

Comment: @aashima There are no issues with your code. Click moves down to your view without any null pointers. Have you cleaned your project?

Comment: Yep.. I verified. Its the right one..

Comment: @DimitarGenov, I see.. No, I haven't..yet. Will give it a go..

Comment: Fixed it... I had made a re-declaration of my TableLayout accidentally. Thats what caused the error .. Thanks for your help :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If anybody gets this problem, its probably cos you have made a re-declaration of some variable accidentally.

That's what caused the error in my program..silly me

Answer (score 0):

I'd say you're crashing because `View child` is null. `getChildAt()` only gets the visible children, so you shouyld use `getChildCount()` and `getFirstVisiblePosition()` to check what is the index of the first visible child and the index of the last visible child by adding count and first visible position.

Also, you could scroll using `smoothScrollToPosition()` to get directly to the child of interest.

Comment: As the table is scrollable, some views can be scrolled outside the screen hence becoming not visible

Comment: Isn't that taken care of by the ScrollView itself? The views outside the screen boundary are brought to view by scrolling..right? Also, what I'm trying to do is, give user easy access to the views far down the ScrollView just by a button click...

Comment: I mean that getChildAt() only returns based on the elements visible on screen. The first visible item (regardless of its actual position on the adapter) will always be 0, the second visible item 1 and so forth. So if you only have 5 items visible in screen, getChildAt(5) will return null.

Comment: The exception is not in `getChildAt`, but in `register`. So according to the statement on that line (as highlighted), only `myTL` can be `null` for NPE.